# One Way Communications Between Model and Support 

Tags: javascript

In the fiddle below, I'd like `Mo` to be able to call `Su` but not the other way around.

How can I implement this.  I don't want to use events.  Just native functionality of JavaScript.

Models are the traditional models found in the MVC.  Support contains support functions needed by the model to run.

Mo -> Su

http://jsfiddle.net/bkYcr/2/

Comment: Do you want to prevent only Su from accessing Mo? I mean can other objects access Mo?

Comment: I don't want anything else accessing Mo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want "anything else accessing Mo", you can make Mo private. It is done by making function `Model` into constructor.

```
$Frame.Model = function(model_object){
    var privateFunc = function() {
        //Private function of Model objects. Can access Su.
    }
    this.publicFunction = function() {
        //Public function of Model objects. Anyone can access this by Mo.publicFunction(). Also can access Su.
    }
}
```

This function is a CONSTRUCTOR. So to make Mo, do

```
Mo = new $Frame.Model();
```

Remember not to forget the new. Or else things get messed up. To prevent the "mess" (which happens because the this inside the constructor refers to `window` if you forget the new), do this:

```
$Frame.Model = function(model_object){

    if (!(this instanceof $Frame.Model))
        return new $Frame.Model();
    var privateFunc = function() {
        //Private function of Model objects. Can access Su.
    }
    this.publicFunction = function() {
        //Public function of Model objects. Anyone can access this by Mo.publicFunction()
    }
}
```